# <body> Gradient background min-height

Tags: html, css, gradient

i got a gradient on the body element.
I set `min-height: 100%;` so the gradient always fills out the viewport. This is working so far.

But i want to set a `min-height: 1000px;` only for the gradient, not the whole page.

A solution would be to use the gradient on a `:before` pseudo element and add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent - but this isnt perfect i think.

Any good solution?

Comment: Nope...gradients don't accept min-heights themselves as they aren't elements (or pseudo-elements).

Comment: Do you mean you want the gradient to go that far, but not be scrollable if there's nothing in the body that low?

Answer (score 3):

I think that a gradient can on html tag with "min-height" property.
https://jsfiddle.net/bearwolf/098hg12g/

```
html{
    border:1px solid #000;
    min-height:1000px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #fefcea, #f1da36);
}

body{
    border:1px solid red;
}

div{
    height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a "wrapper" div inside the body, and give that div the gradient and `min-height: 1000px`

Answer (score 0):

[View DEMO here](https://jsfiddle.net/2z011h55/)

## HTML

```
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">All text goes here</div>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
   *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;   
        box-sizing:border-box;  
    }
     body{          
        display:block;
        position:relative;                              
        text-align:center;          
    }    
    body:before{
        content: "";
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff6000, #ffffff);
        min-height:1000px; 
        position:absolute;
        overflow:hidden;            
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        border:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
    }  
    .wrapper{
        height:500px;
        line-height:500px;
        color:#000000;
        font-size:20px;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;                       
        border:1px solid #000000;
        padding:30px;
        width:500px;
        margin:50px auto;           
        background-color:#fff;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:middle;                  
    }
```